# JSP - Get Server MAC

Tags: jsp

Looking for a way to grab the server MAC address within JSP.

I need to be able to grab this, to license the application to the MAC address level. Is there any viable way to do this?

**edit**

If I were to do it via Java, is there any way I can pass the output to JSP?

Many thanks!

Comment: There's nothing built into Java, this guy makes a couple attempts:  http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-mac-address-in-java/

Comment: Yeah, I saw his. In a comment he said it might be possible if the applet is signed and trusted by the client.

Comment: Yeah I suppose I could use Java and pass the MAC across. Does it have to be trusted to be the server information and not the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using:

http://mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-mac-address-in-java

This works and outputs the MAC, unless you have something like virtualbox installed and it tends to grab that IP 169.x and MAC address instead.

Now to grab the MAC for the JSP..